# Populate Django pdf after submition from user input

Tags: python, html, django

I've done the HTML as well as the pdf blank file for my web framework, but when it comes to the submission POST, I cannot seem to get it to work. Its supposed that once you press the submit it will save the user input to the blank pdf created, to later through a button (which is already created and functional, but downloads blank) download a pdf with the users inputed data. PDF should have the input data

Home1.html

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %} {% block title%} Home2 {%endblock title%}

{%block Formulario%}

form id="survey-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="name-label" for="name">Nombres y Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre:" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="fecha-label" for="Fecha">Fecha</label>
            <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha actual" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="cargo-label" for="cargo">Cargo Actual</label>
            <input type="text" name="cargo_actual" id="cargo_actual" class="form-control" placeholder="Cargo Actual"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Nac-label" for="cargo">Lugar y Fecha de Nacimiento </label>
            <input type="text" name="FechaNac" id="FechaNac" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Lugar y Fecha de Nacimiento"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Discapacidad-label" for="Discapacidad">Discapacidad </label>
            <input type="text" name="Discapacidad" id="Discapacidad" class="form-control" placeholder="En caso de tener discapacidad ingrese el grado,caso contrario deje vacio"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Edad-label" for="Edad">Edad </label>
            <input type="number" name="Edad" id="Edad" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Edad" min="18" max="90"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Tipo_Sangre-label" for="Tipo_Sangre">Tipo de Sangre </label>
            <input type="text" name="Tipo_Sangre" id="Tipo_Sangre" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su tipo de Sangre"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Estatura-label" for="Estatura">Estatura: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Estatura" id="Estatura" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Estatura"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Direccion_Domicilio-label" for="Direccion_Domicilio_actual">Direccion de Domicilio Actual </label>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion_Domicilio_actual" id="Direccion_Domicilio_actual" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su direccion de domicilio actual"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Manzana-label" for="Manzana">Manzana </label>
            <input type="text" name="Manzana" id="Manzana" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la Manzana de la vivienda"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Parroquia-label" for="Parroquia">Parroquia </label>
            <input type="text" name="Parroquia" id="Parroquia" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la Parroquia"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Telefono_Domicilio-label" for="Telefono_Domicilio">Telefono Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Domicilio" id="Telefono_Domicilio" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su telefono domiciliario"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Telefono_Celular-label" for="Telefono_Celular">Telefono Celular </label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Celular" id="Telefono_Celular" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su telefono celular"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Telefono_Familiar-label" for="Telefono_Familiar">Telefono Familiar </label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Familiar" id="Telefono_Familiar" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su telefono familiar"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Cedula-label" for="Cedula">Cedula </label>
            <input type="text" name="Cedula" id="Cedula" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su cedula"/>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Cual es su estado civil?</p>
            <select id="dropdown" name="estado_civil" class="form-control" required/>
            <option disabled selected value>Seleccione alguna opcion</option>
            <option value="chat">Soltero</option>
            <option value="photo">Union Libre</option>
            <option value="live">   Casadio </option>
            <option value="story">Viudo</option>
            <option value="story">Divorciado</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <h2> Informacion del Conyuge o Esposo <span class="clue">(En caso de no tener, dejar vacio)</span></h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Nombre_del_Conyuge-label" for="Nombre_del_Conyuge">Nombre Completo del Conyuge </label>
            <input type="text" name="Nombre_del_Conyuge" id="Nombre_del_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese nombre de su esposo/a"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge-label" for="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge">Direccion Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge" id="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese direccion del domicilio:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Telefono_Conyuge-label" for="Telefono_Conyuge">Telefono: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Conyuge" id="Telefono_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese telefono:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Cedula_Conyuge-label" for="Cedula_Conyuge">Cedula: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Cedula_Conyuge" id="Cedula_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese cedula:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="FechaNac_Conyuge-label" for="FechaNac_Conyuge">Fecha de Nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="date" name="FechaNac_Conyuge" id="FechaNac_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese fecha de Nacimiento:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Lugar_Trabajo_Conyuge-label" for="Lugar_Trabajo_Conyuge">Lugar de trabajo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Lugar_Trabajo_Conyuge" id="Lugar_Trabajo_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el lugar de trabajo:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge-label" for="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge">Direccion Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge" id="Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese direccion del domicilio:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Telefono_Trabajo-label" for="Telefono_Trabajo">Telefono del Trabajo: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Trabajo" id="Telefono_Trabajo" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese telefono del trabajo"/>
          </div>

          <h2> Informacion de los Hijos <span class="clue">(En caso de no tener hijos, dejar vacio)</span></h2>

          <small> Hijo 1 </small>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NombreK1-label" for="NombreK1">Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NombreK1" id="NombreK1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NacK1-label" for="NacK1">Fecha y Lugar de Nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NacK1" id="NacK1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese fecha y lugar de nacimiento:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="EdadK1-label" for="EdadK1"> Edad: </label>
            <input type="text" name="EdadK1" id="EdadK1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la edad:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="CedulaK1-label" for="CedulaK1">Cedula: </label>
            <input type="text" name="CedulaK1" id="CedulaK1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese cedula:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="DireccionK1-label" for="DireccionK1">Direccion Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="DireccionK1" id="DireccionK1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese direccion del domicilio:"/>
          </div>
          <small> Hijo 2 </small>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NombreK2-label" for="NombreK2">Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NombreK2" id="NombreK2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NacK2-label" for="NacK2">Fecha y Lugar de Nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NacK2" id="NacK2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese fecha y lugar de nacimiento:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="EdadK2-label" for="EdadK2"> Edad: </label>
            <input type="text" name="EdadK2" id="EdadK2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la edad:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="CedulaK2-label" for="CedulaK2">Cedula: </label>
            <input type="text" name="CedulaK2" id="CedulaK2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese cedula:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="DireccionK2-label" for="DireccionK2">Direccion Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="DireccionK2" id="DireccionK2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese direccion del domicilio:"/>
          </div>
          <small> Hijo 3 </small>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NombreK3-label" for="NombreK3">Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NombreK3" id="NombreK3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NacK3-label" for="NacK3">Fecha y Lugar de Nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NacK3" id="NacK3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese fecha y lugar de nacimiento:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="EdadK3-label" for="EdadK3"> Edad: </label>
            <input type="text" name="EdadK3" id="EdadK3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la edad:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="CedulaK3-label" for="CedulaK3">Cedula: </label>
            <input type="text" name="CedulaK3" id="CedulaK3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese cedula:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="DireccionK3-label" for="DireccionK3">Direccion Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="DireccionK3" id="DireccionK3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese direccion del domicilio:"/>
          </div>
          <small> Hijo 1 </small>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NombreK4-label" for="NombreK4">Nombre: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NombreK4" id="NombreK4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NacK4-label" for="NacK4">Fecha y Lugar de Nacimiento: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NacK4" id="NacK4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese fecha y lugar de nacimiento:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="EdadK4-label" for="EdadK4"> Edad: </label>
            <input type="tex4" name="EdadK4" id="EdadK4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la edad:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="CedulaK4-label" for="CedulaK4">Cedula: </label>
            <input type="text" name="CedulaK4" id="CedulaK4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese cedula:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="DireccionK4-label" for="DireccionK4">Direccion Domicilio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="DireccionK4" id="DireccionK4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese direccion del domicilio:"/>
          </div>
          <h2> Informacion Familiares <span class="clue"> (Padres y hermanos) </span></h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Apellidos_Nombres-label" for="Apellidos_Nombres">Apellidos y Nombres completos: </label>
            <small> Hijo 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Apellidos_NombresF1" id="Apellidos_NombresF1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Apellidos_NombresF2" id="Apellidos_NombresF2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 3 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Apellidos_NombresF3" id="Apellidos_NombresF3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Telefono_Familiares-label" for="Telefono_Familiares">Telefono: </label>
            <small> Hijo 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Familiares1" id="Telefono_Familiares1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Familiares2" id="Telefono_Familiares2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 3 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Telefono_Familiares3" id="Telefono_Familiares3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Fecha_NacimientoFam-label" for="Apellidos_Nombres">Fecha de Nacimiento: </label>
            <small> Hijo 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Fecha_NacimientoFam1" id="Fecha_NacimientoFam1" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono"/>
            <small> Hijo 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Fecha_NacimientoFam2" id="Fecha_NacimientoFam2" class="form-control" placeholder=" Telefono:"/>
            <small> Hijo 3 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Fecha_NacimientoFam3" id="Fecha_NacimientoFam3" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefono:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Relacion_Parentesco-label" for="Relacion_Parentesco">Relacion de Parentesco </label>
            <small> Hijo 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Relacion_ParentescoF1" id="Relacion_ParentescoF1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Relacion_ParentescoF2" id="Relacion_ParentescoF2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 3 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Relacion_ParentescoF3" id="Relacion_ParentescoF3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Direccion_Familiares-label" for="Direccion_Familiares">Apellidos y Nombres completos: </label>
            <small> Hijo 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion_FamiliaresF1" id="Direccion_FamiliaresF1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion_FamiliaresF2" id="Direccion_FamiliaresF2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Hijo 3 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion_FamiliaresF3" id="Direccion_FamiliaresF3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id='inp_3-label' for="inp_3"> Trabajan en esta empresa familiares?
                <input type="checkbox" name="inp_Si" id= "inp_3" class='form-control'>Si </input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inp_No" id='inp_3' class='form-control'>No </input>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id='inp_4-label' for="inp_4"> Trabajan en esta empresa amistades?
                <input type="checkbox" name="inp_Si" id= "inp_4" class='form-control'>Si </input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inp_No" id='inp_4' class='form-control'>No </input>
            </label>
          </div>
          <h2> Referencias Personales<span class="clue"> (diferentes a familiares) </span></h2>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Apellidos_NombresRef-label" for="Apellidos_NombresRef">Apellidos y Nombres completos: </label>
            <small> Referencia 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Apellidos_NombresRef1" id="Apellidos_NombresRef1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
            <small> Referencia 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Apellidos_NombresREf2" id="Apellidos_NombresRef2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos y Nombres:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Direccion_DomicilioRef-label" for="Direccion_DomicilioRef">Apellidos y Nombres completos: </label>
            <small> Referencia 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion_DomicilioRef1" id="Direccion_DomicilioRef1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Domicilio:"/>
            <small> Referencia 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="Direccion_DomicilioRef2" id="Direccion_DomicilioRef2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="TelefonoRef-label" for="TelefonoRef">Telefono: </label>
            <small> Referencia 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="TelefonoRef1" id="TelefonoRef1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Telefono:"/>
            <small> Referencia 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="TelefonoRef2" id="TelefonoRef2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Telefono:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Ocupacion-label" for="Ocupacion">Ocupacion: </label>
            <small> Referencia 1 </small>
            <input type="text" name="OcupacionRef1" id="OcupacionRef1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Ocupacion:"/>
            <small> Referencia 2 </small>
            <input type="text" name="OcupacionRef2" id="OcupacionRef2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese Ocupacion:"/>
          </div>
          <h2> Experiencia Laboral <span class="clue"> (si tiene menos de tres anos en la empresa) </span></h2> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NombreEmpresa-label" for="NombreEmpresa"> Nombre de la Empresa: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NombreEmpresa" id="NombreEmpresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la Empresa:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="DireccionEmpresa-label" for="DireccionEmpresa"> Direccion de la Empresa: </label>
            <input type="text" name="DireccionEmpresa" id="DireccionEmpresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la Direccion de la Empresa:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="TelefonoEmpresa-label" for="TelefonoEmpresa"> Telefono de la Empresa: </label>
            <input type="text" name="TelefonoEmpresa" id="TelefonoEmpresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el telefono:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="FechaIngreso-label" for="FechaIngreso">  Fecha de Ingreso: </label>
            <input type="text" name="FechaIngreso" id="FechaIngreso" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha en la cual inicio:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="FechaSalida-label" for="FechaSalida"> Fecha de Salida: </label>
            <input type="text" name="FechaSalida" id="FechaSalida" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la fehca de salida:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Sueldo-label" for="Sueldo"> Sueldo Final: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Sueldo" id="Sueldo" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Sueldo:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Cargo-label" for="Cargo"> Cargo que llevaba: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Cargo" id="Cargo" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su cargo:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Tiempo_Servicio-label" for="Tiempo_Servicio"> Tiempo de Servicio: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Tiempo_Servicio" id="Tiempo_Servicio" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el tiempo que estuvo en la empresa:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="Jefe_Inmediato-label" for="Jefe_Inmediato"> Jefe Inmediato: </label>
            <input type="text" name="Jefe_Inmediato" id="Jefe_Inmediato" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese su Jefe:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="NombreEmpresa-label" for="NombreEmpresa"> Nombre de la Empresa: </label>
            <input type="text" name="NombreEmpresa" id="NombreEmpresa" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la Empresa:"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id='Vehiculo-label' for="inp_3"> Usted posee un vehiculo?
                <input type="checkbox" name="inp_SiVehiculo" id= "inp_4Vehiculo" class='form-control'>Si </input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inp_NoVehiculo" id='inp_4Vehiculo' class='form-control'>No </input>
            </label>
          </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label id="ModeloV-label" for="ModeloV"> Vehiculo: </label>
                <input type="text" name="ModeloV" id="ModeloV" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el modelo del Vehiculo:"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label id="MarcaV-label" for="MarcaV"> Marca: </label>
                <input type="text" name="MarcaV" id="MarcaV" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la marca del Vehiculo:"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label id="PlacaV-label" for="PlacaV"> Placa: </label>
                <input type="text" name="PlacaV" id="PlacaV" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la placa de su vehiculo:"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label id="AnoV-label" for="AnoV"> Año del Vehiculo: </label>
                <input type="text" name="AnoV" id="AnoV" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el año del vehiculo :"/>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label id="ColorV-label" for="ColorV"> Color: </label>
                <input type="text" name="ColorV" id="ColorV" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el color del vehiculo:"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Su vivienda actual es?</p>
                <select id="dropdown" name="Vivienda" class="form-control" required/>
                <option disabled selected value>Seleccione alguna opcion</option>
                <option value="Propia">Propia</option>
                <option value="Alquilada">Alquilada</option>
                <option value="Familiar"> Familiar </option>
                </select>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
                <p>Cual es el tipo de vivienda?</p>
                <select id="dropdown" name="TipoVivienda" class="form-control" required/>
                <option disabled selected value>Seleccione alguna opcion</option>
                <option value="Hormigon">Hormigon</option>
                <option value="Mixta">   Mixta </option>
                <option value="Madera">Madera</option>

                </select>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label id='Terrenos-label' for="inp_5"> Usted posee Terrenos?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="inp_SiTerreno" id= "inp_5Vehiculo" class='form-control'>Si </input>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="inp_NoTerreno" id='inp_5Vehiculo' class='form-control'>No </input>
                </label>
              </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit-button">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
  

<style>

body{
    background-color: #05c4c4;
    font-family: Verdana;
    text-align:center;

}

form{
    background-color:fff;
    max-width:100px
    margin= 10px auto;
    padding=30px 20px;
    box-shadow:2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}
.form-control {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.form-control label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-control input,
.form-control select,
.form-control textarea {
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
}

.form-control input[type="radio"],
.form-control input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
button {
    background-color: #05c4c4;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 21px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h4 {
  background-color: #05c4c4;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align:left;
  margin: 10px
}
</style>

{% endblock Formulario%}
```

views.py

```
def home2_pdf(request):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    c = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
    textob= c.beginText()
    textob.setTextOrigin(inch,inch)
    textob.setFont("Helvetica", 14)

    lines =[
       request.POST['name'],
       request.POST['fecha'],
       request.POST['cargp_actual'],
       request.POST['FechaNac'],
       request.POST['Discapacidad'],
       request.POST['Edad'],
       request.POST['Tipo_Sangre'],
       request.POST['Estatura'],
       request.POST['Direccion_Domicilio_actual'],
       request.POST['Manzana'],
       request.POST['Parroquia'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Domicilio'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Celular'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Familiar'],
       request.POST['Cedula'],
       request.POST['estado_civil'],
       request.POST['Nombre_del_Conyuge'],
    
    ]

    for line in lines:
        textob.textLine(line)

    c.drawText(textob)
    c.showPage()
    c.save()
    buf.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename="formulario.pdf")
```

urls.py snip

```
path('home2_pdf', home2_pdf, name='home2_pdf'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your html form does not have name attributes, not sure how you going to access those input in the request.POST, I'm giving the solution while assuming that your input have the name attribute, you could have listed your posted data that empty lines in your `view.py` list like this

```
lines = [
         request.POST['fecha'], 
         request.POST['cargo'],
        ]
```

Comment: thanks so much, Ill add the attribute name="" to my inputs to later add them to the list thanks. Ill update if works

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError at /home2_pdf
'name'

I continue to get this error when trying to append this kind of way to the list

Comment: That means you're calling something that is not in your html form. Just try with those two inputs `fecha` and `cargo` but make sure in your html you have name="fecha" and name="cargo"

Comment: <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la fecha actual" required/>

I have, to each input data I've added this type of name="fecha", but the request.POSsays there doesn't exist any input this way, I'll update the HTML form

Comment: Check this example on GitHub [How to generate PDF from posted data in Django](https://github.com/peter88tom/create_pdf_from_post)

Comment: Thanks so much, I have completed the generation of the pdf, I'll update the post accordingly, I was missing the render statement

Comment: I'm trying to figure out as it return a multivaluedicterror, even do some fields are not required, they are passed through POST but if empy should'nt be written in file

Comment: Ok, then you have to check for each input if does exist in the request first before putting it into your list. You can do that like `if "cargo" in request.POST`  then append to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In your `views.py` you are not adding any lines to your PDF

```py
        lines =[
        
        ]
        for line in lines:
            textob.textLine(line)
```

You have to use the `request.POST` data to construct the lines you like to have in your PDF file.
We can't help you any further, as we do not know what the lines should be you like to have in your PDF.

Comment: Lines are the user input that is on the home.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the final answer on the writing to a PDF after submit using HTML directly

views.py

```
def home2_pdf(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        c = canvas.Canvas(buf, pagesize=letter, bottomup=0)
        textob = c.beginText()
        textob.setTextOrigin(10, 73)
        textob.setFont("Helvetica", 14)

        lines = [
       request.POST['name'],
       request.POST['fecha'],
       request.POST['cargo_actual'],
       request.POST['FechaNac'],
       request.POST['Discapacidad'],
       request.POST['Edad'],
       request.POST['Tipo_Sangre'],
       request.POST['Estatura'],
       request.POST['Direccion_Domicilio_actual'],
       request.POST['Manzana'],
       request.POST['Parroquia'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Domicilio'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Celular'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Familiar'],
       request.POST['Cedula'],
       request.POST['estado_civil'],
       request.POST.get('Nombre_del_Conyuge', False),
       request.POST.get("Dirrecion_Domicilio_Conyuge", False),
       request.POST['Telefono_Conyuge'],
       request.POST['Cedula_Conyuge'],
       request.POST['FechaNac_Conyuge'],
       request.POST['Lugar_Trabajo_Conyuge'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Trabajo'],
       request.POST['NombreK1'],
       request.POST['NacK1'],
       request.POST['EdadK1'],
       request.POST['CedulaK1'],
       request.POST['DireccionK1'],
       request.POST['NombreK2'],
       request.POST['NacK2'],
       request.POST['EdadK2'],
       request.POST['CedulaK2'],
       request.POST['DireccionK2'],
       request.POST['NombreK3'],
       request.POST['NacK3'],
       request.POST['EdadK3'],
       request.POST['CedulaK3'],
       request.POST['DireccionK3'],
       request.POST['NombreK4'],
       request.POST['NacK4'],
       request.POST['EdadK4'],
       request.POST['CedulaK4'],
       request.POST['DireccionK4'],
       request.POST['Apellidos_NombresF1'],
       request.POST['Apellidos_NombresF2'],
       request.POST['Apellidos_NombresF3'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Familiares1'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Familiares2'],
       request.POST['Telefono_Familiares3'],
       request.POST['Fecha_NacimientoFam1'],
       request.POST['Fecha_NacimientoFam2'],
       request.POST['Fecha_NacimientoFam3'],
       request.POST['Relacion_ParentescoF1'],
       request.POST['Relacion_ParentescoF2'],
       request.POST['Relacion_ParentescoF3'],
       request.POST['Direccion_FamiliaresF1'],
       request.POST['Direccion_FamiliaresF2'],
       request.POST['Direccion_FamiliaresF3'],
       request.POST.get('inp_SiFam', False),
       request.POST.get('inp_NoFam', False),
       request.POST.get('inp_SiAm', False),
       request.POST.get('inp_NoAm', False),
       request.POST['Apellidos_NombresRef1'],
       request.POST.get('Apellidos_NombresRef2', False),
       request.POST['Direccion_DomicilioRef1'],
       request.POST['Direccion_DomicilioRef2'],
       request.POST['TelefonoRef1'],
       request.POST['TelefonoRef2'],
       request.POST['OcupacionRef1'],
       request.POST['OcupacionRef2'],
       request.POST['NombreEmpresa'],
       request.POST['DireccionEmpresa'],
       request.POST['TelefonoEmpresa'],
       request.POST['FechaIngreso'],
       request.POST['FechaSalida'],
       request.POST['Sueldo'],
       request.POST['Cargo'],
       request.POST['Tiempo_Servicio'],
       request.POST['Jefe_Inmediato'],
       request.POST['NombreEmpresa'],
       request.POST.get('inp_SiVehiculo', False),
       request.POST.get('inp_NoVehiculo', False),
       request.POST['ModeloV'],
       request.POST['MarcaV'],
       request.POST['PlacaV'],
       request.POST['AnoV'],
       request.POST['ColorV'],
       request.POST['Vivienda'],
       request.POST['TipoVivienda'],
       request.POST.get('inp_SiTerreno', False),
       request.POST.get('inp_NoTerreno', False),

        ]

        for line in lines:
            textob.textLine(line)

        c.drawText(textob)
        c.showPage()
        c.save()
        buf.seek(0)

        return FileResponse(buf, as_attachment=True, filename="formulario.pdf")

    return render(request, 'users/Home2.html')
```